# Are the answers to Apple ID security questions 100% useless to a hacker once 2FA has been set up?

Tags: security, apple-id

If my security answers were compromised, do I need to worry about those answers being "in the wild" now that I have 2FA set up? (Because now I can't change them). If you can support your answer with official reference/link that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> do I need to worry about those answers being "in the wild" now that I have 2FA set up?

Yes.  There are two main reasons:

- if you used these answers for any other account, there is now a method to compromise those accounts
- 2FA is very good, but not foolproof

From [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915):

> Two-factor authentication is *an extra layer of security* for your Apple
> ID, designed to make sure that you're the only one who can access your
> account—even if someone else knows your password

Normally, you would reset your passwords using a trusted device, but what if you no longer have access to those trusted devices? This is the scenario a hacker could use to gain access to your account.

Apple would go through a series of manual verifications before they re-enable access to your account. If your email and phone number are known to the attacker, it makes spoofing your identity that much easier.

If you used these security questions/answers  anywhere else, you would be best advised to change them.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. Let's assume that these are not used anywhere else. Do you know... could the hacker use them in some way to assist with manual verification, or has Apple actually deleted these answers rendering them useless. If they are in fact even slightly useful, Apple should provide a way to change them? How is it even possible to change them once 2FA is set up?

Comment: Like i mentioned, if they know your phone number, they could claim it was lost/stolen, but would be able to give it to Apple.  If they’ve gained access to your email, they could say it’s no longer used and give Apple another.  Lots of puzzle pieces, but they now have two important ones in their possession.

Comment: This question seems to imply that security questions could still be used to reset your password even with 2FA. This is false: "If you don't want security questions or you're concerned about forgetting the answers, you can set up two-factor authentication." https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201363

Comment: @Ezekiel, it may not be easy, but its doable. 2FA can fail when you no longer have access to your trusted device.  Apple addresses it in the link I supplied. **Nothing is 100% secure**.

Comment: Right, but it **does not fallback to security questions.** So if your security question "What' is my dog's name" is compromised, that's not useful to directly compromise an Apple ID.

Comment: @Ezekiel,  Have you ever **manually** verified an account with Apple?  I have and they ask the security questions as part of their process. I never said in my answer that “it falls back to security questions.”  You’re creating and rebutting a point never asserted .

Comment: Apple Support cannot reset a password, so while I cannot speak to the manual verification process with Apple, I can speak to what they can do with your account. Resetting your account details is not an option.

The only way to gain access to an account when you don't know your password is to use a trusted device to reset it, or to use iforgot.apple.com and go through the automated recovery process. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204921

Comment: @Ezekiel, I said none of that. What said about “the only way to access an account” is wholly incorrect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141590/discussion-between-ezekiel-and-allan).

Answer (score 1):

> If my security answers were compromised, do I need to worry about those answers being "in the wild" now that I have 2FA set up?

In the context of your Apple account – and specifically the idea that the questions could be answered to reset your password, no.

When you enable two-factor authentication, your security questions cannot be used to modify/reset your account access.

From [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201363):

> Two-factor authentication is the most secure way to protect your Apple ID. If you haven't set up two-factor authentication for your account, Apple uses security questions to provide you with a secondary method to identify yourself online.

> If you don't want security questions or you're concerned about forgetting the answers, you can set up two-factor authentication.

Of course, any personal information could still be used in other ways, i.e. phishing/social engineering. Note that the recovery process for your Apple account is strictly automated and requires access to a phone number or email address to complete.

If your attacker could determine this information, they could attack your phone or email accounts and use them to reset your Apple ID. However, this is an involved process, and not directly related to your security questions in particular.